# R: Extract list columns based on column names and patterns

Tags: r, list, indexing, extract

I have a list  (here only sample data)

```
my_list <- list(structure(list(sample = c(2L, 6L), data1 = c(56L, 78L), 
    data2 = c(59L, 27L), data3 = c(90L, 28L), data1namet = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), .Label = "Sam1", class = "factor"), data2namab = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), .Label = "Test2", class = "factor"), dataame = structure(c(1L, 
    1L), .Label = "Ex3", class = "factor"), ma = c("Jay", "Jay"
    )), .Names = c("sample", "data1", "data2", "data3", "data1namet", 
"data2namab", "dataame", "ma"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(sample = c(12L, 13L, 17L), data1 = c(56L, 
    78L, 3L), data2 = c(59L, 27L, 2L), datest = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Exa9", class = "factor"), dattestr = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "cz1", class = "factor"), add = c(2, 2, 
    2)), .Names = c("sample", "data1", "data2", "datest", "dattestr", 
    "add"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"))

my_list
[[1]]
  sample data1 data2 data3 data1namet data2namab dataame  ma
1      2    56    59    90       Sam1      Test2     Ex3 Jay
2      6    78    27    28       Sam1      Test2     Ex3 Jay

[[2]]
  sample data1 data2 datest dattestr add
1     12    56    59   Exa9      cz1   2
2     13    78    27   Exa9      cz1   2
3     17     3     2   Exa9      cz1   2
```

I've got two problems:
I would like to extract columns in this list based on patterns of their column names, e.g. all columns which contain the word 'data' in their column name. I wasn't able to find a solution with `grep`.

I know how to extract one column based on their index number (see example below), but how could I do this selection directly based on the column name (not the column number)?

```
out <- lapply(my_list, `[`, 1) # extract "sample" column
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
lapply(my_list, function(df) df[, grep("data", names(df), fixed = TRUE)] )
# [[1]]
# data1 data2 data3 data1namet data2namab dataame
# 1    56    59    90       Sam1      Test2     Ex3
# 2    78    27    28       Sam1      Test2     Ex3
# 
# [[2]]
# data1 data2
# 1    56    59
# 2    78    27
# 3     3     2

lapply(my_list, "[", "sample")
# [[1]]
# sample
# 1      2
# 2      6
# 
# [[2]]
# sample
# 1     12
# 2     13
# 3     17
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `fixed=TRUE` here?

Comment: No specific reason. Just got used to it when looking for a fixed string like - in this case - _"data"_. Performance! ;-)

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot. is there a way I could make multiple selections, e.g. select all columns that contain "sample" and all columns that contain  "data" in their respective column names?

Comment: one way would be to use a regular expression with OR (pipe): `grep("data|sample", names(df))`

Comment: when i use this code and run it, 'Undefined dimensions' error is displayed. Please help me